# while loop not working correctly with the > token

Tags: javascript

This does not seem to be working I am not sure how to get this while loop to work correctly any help would be appreciated.

```
function getProductCode() {
   productCode = parseInt(prompt("Enter Product Code: "));
   while (productCode < 1 || > 9999) 
   {
      document.writeln("Error! the product Code must be between 1 - 9999");
      parseInt(prompt("Enter Product Code: "));
   }
   return productCode
}

getProductCode()
```

Comment: What is "not working correctly"? What is happening and what do you expect to happen instead?

Comment: well the < 1 || > 9999 bit if you check the web console it says > is an unexpected token why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing an operand (`productCode`) at the left side:

```
while (productCode < 1 || productCode > 9999) 
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

And:

- Supply a radix to [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt). When unspecified, `010` becomes 8 (octal literal).
- Do not leak variables to the global scope, use [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) to declare local variables.
- Invert your logic, or use [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN). When an invalid number is supplied ([`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN)), your loop should not stop.
- It's better to move the message from `document.writeln` to the dialog.
- Assign the new value to `productCode`. Otherwise, you won't get far...
- **Important**: Dialogs can be disabled in browsers. Do not loop infinitely many times, but add a treshold.

Final code which takes care of the first 5 bullet points:

```
function getProductCode() {
   var productCode = parseInt(prompt("Enter Product Code: "), 10);
   while (!(productCode >= 1 && productCode <= 9999)) {
      productCode = parseInt(prompt("Error! the product Code must be between 1 - 9999\nEnter Product Code: "), 10);
   }
   return productCode;
}
```

I have not implemented the treshold, it's up to you to do that.

Comment: why does my loop keep repeating when i enter a number less than 1 or greater than 9999, how do you break it once i enter a valid number because it just keeps looping now

Comment: function getProductCode() {
 productCode = parseInt(prompt("Enter Product Code: "));
 while (!(productCode >= 1 || productCode =< 9999))
 {
  document.writeln("Error! Product Code must be between (1 - 9999)");
  parseInt(prompt("Enter Product Code: "));
 } 
 return productCode
    }

    getProductCode()

Comment: by the way productCode is going to be a array of 6.

Comment: I'm just wondering... How looped `parseInt()` tackles the octal-issue (bullet point one)?

Answer (score 2):

it should be:

```
while (productCode < 1 || productCode > 9999)
```

Answer (score 0):

`(productCode < 1 || > 9999)` is not a syntactically valid expression

You probably want `(productCode < 1 || productCode > 9999)`